# PHP HTTP Request slow to a particular server

Tags: linux, php, redhat, http

I am making http requests using both curl and file_get_contents. If i make these requests to a particular server, it takes a very long time, sometimes even fails. However, if I make requests to any other site, using the exact same code, the response is lightning speed. The weird part is that if I make the request from my dev server, which is on the same box. I can reach the problematic site at the same lightning speed. So it seems like it is an issue with my production server and the remote server. I was wondering could this be throttling? I am not getting any response stating that my limit has been reached. The funny part is that it use to work at lightning speed, and then about two weeks ago it slowed down. I am not a system admin, so I don't know where to start. Has anyone had this issue? Or does anyone have a ideas to what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use apache or NginX on your server, with FastCGI or not?
Look at [this stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyRIs.png), here is the difference.
Maybe server is out of RAM or CPU what is going to be failed request from your side. Maybe the VPS provider just kidding you cos "better offers" have more bandwith use?

Look, for example clear VPS with apache(~50-60% RAM in 2nd day) and second with nginx(~8% RAM). This was only simple installation in my VPS, for just comparison.

Someone maybe broke your security and you have an malware in your server?

Please give an detailed description. Technical if you can.